# How to close web browser during thread and how to set thread on a timer in Python Selenium Firefox?

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, loops, firefox

How do I close the browser down and reopen it when the thread loops? Is there an easier way to write this code? Also is there a way to set a timer for how long I want all of this to run for? I tried to set another loop as an outer loop, but it just kept opening up more web browsers. Is there a way to incorporate multiprocessing and integrate a VPN switcher in it?

```py
import random
import threading
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

driver_service = Service(executable_path="C:\\Program Files\\geckodriver.exe")
count = 5

def get_it(driver):
    while True:
        driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')
        time.sleep(random.randint(5, 10))
for x in range(2):
    for i in range(count):
        browserThread = threading.Thread(target=get_it, args=(webdriver.Firefox(),))
        browserThread.start()
```

I have tried everything from `driver.quit()` to `driver.close()` and it stops my threads from running and causes errors.

For the loop on the thread I tried an outer loop with no success, and it just kept opening up web browsers more than I had set.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are trying to achieve. Please be a bit more specific on what you are trying to accomplish. There may be a better way to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Where what I did was create the ***driver*** inside the function. Which allows you to reopen and close the browser as you want. I had to remove the while loop because I did not understand why you needed that. And threading depends on your machine's resources. So creating a double for loop to use thread will not give a performance advantage. So I stuck to one.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import random
import threading

count = 10

def get_it():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())  #chrome always to easily maintain the driver.
    # Use proxy to configure different IP.# 
    driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')
    time.sleep(random.randint(5, 10))
    driver.quit()
  

for i in range(count):
    browserThread = threading.Thread(target=get_it)
    browserThread.start()
```

If you declare the *driver* inside the function scope, it will create a new browser instance and run your code.
In my experience, the cause of browser closing errors in a thread is because of the function scope.
You should set the scope perfectly then you are good to go.

And for the VPN, you can use a proxy in selenium. Try googling; you will find some solutions to integrate them in code.

Comment: I am unable to import ChromeDriverManager, WebDriverWait on Selenium

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/
 install chromedrivermanager and for wait... share the traceback